# oidc-client.min.js - Uncaught (in promise) ErrorResponse: login_required

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using React and IdentityServer for Authentication.
I use 'code' grant with 'PKCE'.
When my React app tries to hit an endpoint, If it gets 401 (UNAUTHORIZED), It'll start the login process with OIDC client. Everything works very well.
Except after successful login, I'm seeing a lot of errors in my console coming from 'oidc-client.js.

> Here's a video demonstration -
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzWppuYhrKg

This is my IDP config for this client (Serialized for readability):

```json
{
  "_id": "****",
  "Enabled": true,
  "ProtocolType": "oidc",
  "ClientSecrets": 
  [
    {
      "Value": "****",
      "Type": "SharedSecret"
    }
  ],
  "RequireClientSecret": true,
  "ClientName": "****",
  "RequireConsent": false,
  "AllowRememberConsent": true,
  "AllowedGrantTypes": 
  [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials"
  ],
  "RequirePkce": true,
  "AllowPlainTextPkce": false,
  "RequireRequestObject": false,
  "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": false,
  "RedirectUris": 
  [
    "https://localhost:44410/callback",
    "https://authmanager.twileloop.com/callback"
  ],
  "PostLogoutRedirectUris": 
  [
    "https://localhost:44326/signout-callback-oidc"
  ],
  "FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
  "BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
  "AllowOfflineAccess": false,
  "AllowedScopes": 
  [
    "openid",
    "read",
    "write"
  ],
  "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": false,
  "IdentityTokenLifetime": 3600,
  "AllowedIdentityTokenSigningAlgorithms": [],
  "AccessTokenLifetime": 3600,
  "AuthorizationCodeLifetime": 300,
  "AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime": 2592000,
  "SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime": 1296000,
  "RefreshTokenUsage": "OneTimeOnly",
  "UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh": false,
  "RefreshTokenExpiration": "Absolute",
  "AccessTokenType": "Jwt",
  "EnableLocalLogin": true,
  "IdentityProviderRestrictions": [],
  "IncludeJwtId": true,
  "Claims": [],
  "AlwaysSendClientClaims": false,
  "ClientClaimsPrefix": "client_",
  "DeviceCodeLifetime": 300,
  "AllowedCorsOrigins": 
  [
    "https://localhost:44410",
    "https://authmanager.twileloop.com"
  ],
  "Properties": {}
}
```

This is my JavaScript config:

```json
const config = {
    authority: AUTHORITY_PROD,
    client_id: '****',
    redirect_uri: ORGIN + '/callback',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid read write',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: ORGIN + '/',
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    automaticSilentRenew: false
};

const userManager = new UserManager(config);

//Login
const login = () => {
    userManager.removeUser();
    userManager.signinRedirect();
};

//Logout
const logout = () => {
    userManager.signoutRedirect();
};
```

## DEMO

1. This is my application
   [image]
2. The moment I refresh, It tries to hit an API endpoint and gets 401. This will start authentication flow, and I'm getting redirected to 'https://auth.twileloop.com' where my IDP is.
   [image]
3. Once I successfully log in, It redirects me back to a callback URL and I get the token and also able to hit API endpoints and get data on console. Well and good
   [image]
4. If I refresh again within some seconds, I started getting continues 'login-required' errors
   [image]

Why am I getting this error? I found someone saying 'Chrome Same Site Cookie' policy is making issue. I tried on Edge but same result.

The fact is – Token is still valid for an hour. I can still use it to hit my API. Token validity is 1hr (60×60 secs). But this error is getting filled continuously every time I refresh the page.

5. Also, localStorage is getting flooded
   [image]

Network Logs
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SESSION MONITOR**

From your video and network trace I see that [OpenID Connect session management](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) is being used. If you look at the OIDC metadata returned from your authorization server, you will see that a `check_session_iframe` URL field is present. This URL returns some JavaScript code.

What is happening is that the library is spinning up a hidden iframe that loads this JavaScript code, which then makes an Ajax request to the authorization server every couple of seconds, to check the login state. The intention is that the SSO cookie will be sent in this request.

However, recent browser restrictions will drop the SSO cookie, since it is from a different domain to the web origin, and thus classified as third-party. The outgoing request includes the `prompt=none` parameter. Because the SSO cookie is not present, the authorization server returns a `login_required` error code. You cannot rely on this flow working in modern browsers, so you must disable the `sessionMonitor` behavior. See the [relevant library code](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/SessionMonitor.js).

**STATE STORE**

If you look at local storage more carefully, you will see that there are two types of entry. The one that contains the PKCE code verifier contains only login state that is not needed across multiple browser tabs. Therefore use session storage so that the entries do not build up. This is the approach my [code example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L31) takes. Meanwhile the user store is where access tokens and user info is stored - this can use a different type of storage.

**FINAL CONFIGURATION**

Update your oidc client configuration with the two new settings here, to solve both of your problems.

```js
const config = {
    authority: AUTHORITY_PROD,
    client_id: '****',
    redirect_uri: ORGIN + '/callback',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid read write',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: ORGIN + '/',
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    stateStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.sessionStorage }),
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    sessionMonitor: false
};
```

**DEBUGGING**

If problems remain, add some `console.log` statements to the oidc client library itself, eg by editing files in the below folder. Maybe start by editing [UserManager.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/UserManager.js#L16) to see why the library has activated session management:

```
node_modules/oidc-client-js
```

Comment: Hi Gary, Few points as inferred from you - I verified the API. It only gives 401 exactly after the token expiry, so that part is verified. Secondly, As you can see I disabled silent_login in JsConfig I have no issues my users redirecting and log in after 1hr. While 'automaticSilentRenew: false' will it try to do the iframe approach? Thirdly, Attached the network log

Comment: Ah - see the final point in my updated answer

Comment: Hey Gary, Thanks. I tried it just now but it didn't seem to work. I attached a quick video of the error in question to get helping minds a better context

Comment: Cool - I see what is happening - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Using the config you provided still gives the same 'login-required' errors with an additional one more error - "oidc-client.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No matching state found in storage at oidc-client.min.js:1:1"

Comment: Looks like you need to debug the library as a next step to see why session management has been activated. I can't do this for you, but I added some notes on how I've done it in the past.

Comment: Hey thanks, Gary. Turns out "sessionMonitor: false" does the trick as you suggested. Using "sessionMonitor: false" along with an open cookie policy change on my server side together was the solution. Kudos !!!

Comment: An extra answer is added with steps I performed to make it work, just in case someone reaches here later

Answer (score 1):

I derived the fix from major points from [Gary's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9019885/gary-archer) answer.

Posting here as it'll be helpful anyone coming here later.

### 1. These changes should go on the client side (React, Angular, SPA's..)

1. Disable `automaticSilentRenew`
2. Disable `monitorSession`

Final client config:

```js
const config = {
    authority: AUTHORITY_PROD,
    client_id: '****',
    redirect_uri: ORGIN + '/callback',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid read write',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: ORGIN + '/',
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    monitorSession: false,
    client_secret: '****',
};
```

### 2. These changes should go at the server side (Whichever server technology is used)

> I'm using IdentityServer built on .NET 7, So these are the config changes required

1. Set `SameSite` cookie policy to `NONE`
2. Set `SecurePolicy` to `ALWAYS`

```cs
 services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
                //Set cookie lifetime
                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(config.IdentityServerCookieLifetime);
            })
            //For local testing only
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            //Configure CORS policy
            .AddCorsPolicyService<MyCORSPolicy>()
            //Fetch OAuth v2 resources from SQLServer
            .AddResourceStore<MyResourceStore>()
            //Fetch OAuth v2 clients from SQLServer
            .AddClientStore<MyClientStore>()
            //Fetch user profiles from SQLServer
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

            //Set cookie policy
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });
```